# CSS dropdown menu issues with floating left

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I'm struggling to get the drop down part of my drop down menu to drop down... I've got a horizontal nav bar and this covers the width of the page. When I first put all the code in when I hovered over the button all the menu would appear over the first button on the menu, I've tried so much and can't get it to work.

Here's my CSS

```
#top {
overflow: hidden;
margin-top: 5px;
float: none;
text-align: left;
}
#mainnav ul {
list-style-type: none;
margin-top: 0px;
margin-right: 0px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
margin-left: 0px;
padding-top: 0px;
padding-right: 0px;
padding-bottom: 0px;
padding-left: 0px;
}
#mainnav a {
width: 14.2857%;
display: block;
float: left;
text-align: center;
text-transform: uppercase;
background-color: rgba(48,48,48,0.50);
color: rgba(255,255,255,1.00);
padding-top: 6px;
padding-bottom: 6px;
font-size: small;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: normal;
}
#mainnav a:hover, #mainnav a:active, #mainnav a:focus, #mainnav a.thispage {
background-color: rgba(48,48,48,1.00);
text-decoration: none;
font-weight: normal;
}
#mainnav ul li:hover > ul{ display:block;}
#mainnav ul ul {display:none; position:fixed;}
#mainnav ul ul li {display: inline-block;}
```

and here's the HTML

```
<header id="top">
    <img src="/images/Logo.png">
    <nav id="mainnav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="/Team/">Our Team</a></li>
            <li><a href="/Gallery/">Gallery</a></li>
            <li><a href="/Services/">Services</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="/Services/Highlights/">Highlights</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/Services/Tints/">Tints</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/Services/Packages/">Packages</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/Services/Extensions/">Extensions</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/Services/Cuts/">Cuts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/Services/Dries/">Dries</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="/Testimonials/">Testimonials</a></li>
            <li><a href="/Contact/" class="thispage">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="/Shop/">Shop</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

So, when I hover on Services the drop down appears horizontally over the Home button and quite small. I want this to drop down and be regular ol' sizes just like the rest of the buttons.

All help appreciated and will be commented in code.

Comment: you should have a look into adding a jsfiddle

Comment: I'll go do one now, cheers

Comment: My JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/1mabsopn/

Comment: you want your li to be positioned relative and your second level ul to be absolute, not fixed

Comment: how about: http://jsfiddle.net/zbtckvou/

Comment: @Pete thanks for the help, can you confirm where I need to position the li as relative, I've fixed the fixed issue placed position:relative on here #mainnav ul li:hover > ul{ display:block; position:relative;} now it's just wider

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/1mabsopn/3/ - you also need to remove overflow:hdden from top

Comment: Thanks for all help, question has been answered now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need any floating to make this work, and it'll actually increase the chances of something screwing up if you do you float.  Here's a non-float solution that retains your original widths:

```
#top {
 margin-top: 5px;
 float: none;
 text-align: left;
}
#mainnav ul {
 list-style: none;
 display: inline;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
#mainnav ul li, #mainnav ul li ul li {
 display: inline-block;
 position: relative;
 width: 14.2857%;
 text-align: center;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 background-color: rgba(48,48,48,0.50);
 padding: 6px 0;
 margin: 0 0 0 -4px;
 font-size: small;
}
#mainnav ul li:hover, #mainnav ul li ul li:hover {
 background-color: rgba(48,48,48,1.00);
 text-decoration: none;
}
#mainnav ul li a, #mainnav ul li ul li {
 color: rgba(255,255,255,1.00);
}
#mainnav ul li ul {
 position: absolute;
 top: 28px;
 left: 0;
 display: none;
 visibility: hidden;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}
#mainnav ul li ul li {
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
}
#mainnav ul li:hover ul {
 display: block;
 opacity: 1;
 visibility: visible;
}
```

Here's a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tc9q3bs9/

Comment: Thanks @coderboi_89 this works much better, only thing is the actual drop down doesn't have the same width as the Services tab, can you suggest how I could make this happen?

Comment: I'm sorry about that, I had been testing in a different site.  Here's an updated version: http://jsfiddle.net/tc9q3bs9/2/.  This one has the width of `#mainnav ul li ul` set to 100% and adds `margin: 0;` to `#mainnav ul li ul li` (I noticed the -4px offset it from the main option).

Answer (score 0):

The main issues are that you header and child lists are getting conflicting styles, and you are applying the positioning to the `a` elements instead of the `li` containing it. So

- Float the `li` not the `a`
- position the child `ul`s as absolute, not fixed
- Don't float the child `li`s so they appear underneath each other
- Display the child `a`s as block and full width, so they line up nicely in a box.

This should work better - http://jsfiddle.net/1mabsopn/1/

```
#top {
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-top: 5px;
    float: none;
    text-align: left;
}
#mainnav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
}
#mainnav ul li {
    float:left;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#mainnav a {
    width: 14.2857%;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background-color: rgba(48, 48, 48, 0.50);
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.00);
    padding-top: 6px;
    padding-bottom: 6px;
    font-size: small;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
}
#mainnav a:hover, #mainnav a:active, #mainnav a:focus, #mainnav a.thispage {
    background-color: rgba(48, 48, 48, 1.00);
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: normal;
}
#mainnav ul li:hover > ul {
    display:block;
}
#mainnav ul ul {
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
}
#mainnav ul ul li {
    display: block;
    float:none;
}
#mainnav ul ul a {
    display:block;
    width:100%;
}
```

Comment: Works a dream, I just need to add my width to it again. Thanks Rhumborl! Do you want to inbox me details for your mention?

Comment: just a quick not - you probably want to specify your li as `#mainnav > ul > li` as the way it is above, all your lis (even second level) will be set to float left

Comment: Yes that would mean you don't need `#mainnav ul ul li { display: block; float:none; }` but if you wrap the top `ul` in another element for whatever reason, it will break down. Swings and roundabouts...

Answer (score 0):

try below,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        #top {
        overflow: hidden;
        margin-top: 5px;
        float: none;
        text-align: left;
        }

        #mainnav ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        margin-top: 0px;
        margin-right: 0px;
        margin-bottom: 0px;
        margin-left: 0px;
        padding-top: 0px;
        padding-right: 0px;
        padding-bottom: 0px;
        padding-left: 0px;
        }

        #mainnav a {
            text-align: center;
            text-transform: uppercase;

            color: rgba(255,255,255,1.00);

            font-size: small;
            font-style: normal;
            font-weight: normal;
            height: 80%;
            width: 100%;
            padding-top: 6px;
            padding-bottom: 6px;
        }
        #mainnav a:hover, #mainnav a:active, #mainnav a:focus, #mainnav a.thispage {
        background-color: rgba(48,48,48,1.00);
        text-decoration: none;
        font-weight: normal;
        }
        #mainnav ul li:hover > ul{ display:block;}
        #mainnav ul li > ul{display:block}
        #mainnav ul li {
            width: 14.2857%;
            float: left;
            background-color: rgba(48,48,48,0.50);
            height: 26px;
            padding-top: 3px;
        }
        #mainnav ul ul {

            display: none;
            position: absolute;
            margin-top: 6px;
        }
        #mainnav ul li > ul li{
            clear: left;
            background-color: red;
            width: 100%;
        }

#mainnav ul ul {display:none; position:fixed;}

#mainnav ul ul li {display: inline-block;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <header id="top">
        <img src="/images/Logo.png">
        <nav id="mainnav">
          <ul>
          <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="/Team/">Our Team</a></li>
          <li><a href="/Gallery/">Gallery</a></li>
          <li><a href="/Services/">Services</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/Services/Highlights/">Highlights</a></li>
                <li><a href="/Services/Tints/">Tints</a></li>
                <li><a href="/Services/Packages/">Packages</a></li>
                <li><a href="/Services/Extensions/">Extensions</a></li>
                <li><a href="/Services/Cuts/">Cuts</a></li>
                <li><a href="/Services/Dries/">Dries</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="/Testimonials/">Testimonials</a></li>
          <li><a href="/Contact/" class="thispage">Contact</a></li>
          <li><a href="/Shop/">Shop</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </header>
</body>
</html>
```